# Device Stage Visual Editor requirements

Tags: javascript, xml, device

Using the device stage visual editor tool, the task requirements only takes xml however I need the requirement to be if this program is installed on the computer then return true else false;

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <![CDATA[
        function hasProgram()
        {
            if(file.exists(c:\program files (x86)\company\program\program.exe)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</script>
```

I got the previous code from a website but it doesn't work and from what I can work out from other websites is this is not doable using the Javascript inside the xml however it is clear that some devices do have something like this at the device stage.

so my question is the part that is in correct the if statement line
and if it is how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a registry key when installing the program so it runs when you type a set command into the run command(windows+r) you can then just check if that registry exists in raw xml and get the exact path even if it is installed in a different location.

use the `ifRegistryExist` command to do this